# C++ simple problem but complicated for me

Tags: c++

I tried to resolve this in my own methods but it seems that this didn't worked.

Why don't the values read into `a` and `b` in `addingdata()` carry over to `read()`?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int adding(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
void addingdata()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "nr" << endl;
}
void read()
{
    int a, b;
    int add;
    add = adding(a, b);
    cout << "Sum is:" << add << endl;
}
int main()
{
    addingdata();
    read();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Your variables go out of scope after you take input from them

Comment: @bo8gdan The presented program does not make any sense. There is no logic.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - It makes sense, but they way he(she) is going around trying to achieve it is wrong.

Comment: You've tried to "_resolve this_", but you haven't told us what _this_ is. What's the problem? What do you expect the code to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: @DumbCoder I think that at least instead of     addingdata();
    read(); there should be      read();   addingdata();

Comment: Read about variable scope in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having trouble understanding the concept of a variable's **scope**.  In other words, how long a variable exists, when it goes away, and so on.

Just because two variables in different scopes have the same name doesn't create any connection between them.

When you first declare an `int` it is uninitialized unless you specifically set it to something.

```
int a;
a = 1;
int b = 2;  // either way is fine for int.
```

"Okay, so I need to declare `a` and `b` in a higher scope then pass them down to the individual functions, right?".

Pretty much yes, but this is where the next concept that will throw you will bite you in the ass.  Your first attempt at a solution will probably look something like this (hint: this won't work)

```
int adding(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
void addingdata(int a, int b)
{
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "nr" << endl;
}
void read(int a, int b)
{
    int add;
    add = adding(a, b);
    cout << "Sum is:" << add << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    addingdata(a, b);
    read(a, b);
    getch();
    return 0;  // your original code lacked a return value.  Most compilers would choke on that.  All compilers SHOULD choke on that.
}
```

The next concept that will get you is that of "passing by **value** versus passing by **reference**.

What happens in the above code is that *copies* of `a` and `b` are passed into `addingdata` and `read`.  The parameters of `addingdata` and `read` are their own variables with their own scope and their own values.  These values are assigned to whatever `a` and `b` were when they're passed in.  Note that `a` and `b` were never initialized.  What is the value of an uninitialized variable?  Whatever happened to be in that memory already.  Debuggers will often initialize "uninitialized" memory to some Obviously Bad value (like 0xCCCCCCCC, which is hexadecimal for 3435973836, an Obviously Wrong value that is easy to spot).

So, the sequence of events will go something like this:

- you declare `a` and b in main(), and do not initialize them.  Their values are garbage: Could be zero, could be -1, could be anything.
- copies of `a` and `b` are passed into `addingdata`.
- `addingdata` writes whatever it gets from "standard in" to its own versions of a and b.
  -- Those versions of `a` and `b` then go out of scope and are destroyed.
- Back in `main`, the uninitalized versions of `a` and `b` are passed into `read`... (which doesn't read anything, it adds them together.  We'll discuss naming in a moment.)
- `read` passes its copies of a and b into adding, which returns their sum.  This value, the result of adding two uninitialized variables together, could be just about anything.
- `read`, using its own copies of `a` and `b`, takes that sum of garbage plus garbage, and writes it to standard out.  This value is unlikely to be what you expected.
- `getch()` waits for any old input from "standard in", and the program exits.

So how do we fix this problem?  Well, as I mentioned, the next concept that will give you problem is "passing by value vs passing by reference".  So we need to pass a and b by reference.  How?  With the reference operator:  `&`.  This is also the "address of" operator, which can be slightly confusing.  C++ is not an easy language to learn.

```
int a = 1;
int& b = a; // references must be initialized to refer to some concrete instance of that particular type.
b = 2;
cout << a; // writes "2" to standard out.
```

And more relevant to this problem:

```
int setToTwo(int& foo)
{
    foo = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    setToTwo(a);
    cout << a; // writes 2.
}
```

So now you know everything you need to make your program work.

But it's still not pretty.  To improve your programs style you need to name your functions better.  "Verb" names and "Noun Verb" (and "Verb Noun") are best.  This name should accurately describe what the function does.  If you need to use "and" to describe what a function does, you probably need two different functions.

So, I suggest you name your functions something like "sum", "read", and "writeSum", in that order.  I also suggest that you not call "sum" from within "writeSum"... otherwise you might need one of those "and" names, which would be bad.

Yikes, that answer escalated quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk a bit about ranges.

In C++ (as in many languages), variables only exist in a given range, in a given area of the program. In your case, the problem comes from the fact that your `a, b` variables read in the `addingdata()` function only exist during the execution of `addingdata`, so when your function returns, these values are lost.

Here is your code commented with the variables at each step :

```cpp
int adding(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
void addingdata()
{
    // STEP 2 : No variable is defined
    int a, b;
    // STEP 3 : a and b are defined, but will only live until the end of the function
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "nr" << endl;
    // STEP 4 : a and b only exist in this function so they are destroyed

}
void read()
{
    // STEP 6 : You create brand new variables a and b, you could also have named them alice and bob
    int a, b;
    int add;
    // STEP 7 : Here a and b exist but are not initialized. Their value is unknown
    add = adding(a, b);
    cout << "Sum is:" << add << endl;
}
int main()
{
    // STEP 1 : Here, no variable is defined.
    addingdata();
    // STEP 5 : a and b were destroyed, so they do not exist here 
    read();
    getch();
}
```

So, in order to send the values of `a` and `b` to the `read` function, you must do 2 things :

- Add a `return` statement to your `addingdata` function so that it returns the values it read
- Add two arguments to `read` so that it receives the `a` and `b` values